# How to sort List of MatOfPoints according to contour (x,y)

Tags: java, android, opencv

I have a list that contains MatOfPoints which are nothing but contours that I detected from a image using `opencv`.
How do I sort a `List<MatOfPoints>` according to `x` and `y` coordinate of those contours?

I know that `List` has a `sort` method but I am confused by the `Comparator` parameter.

Comment: if you're confused by Comparator, why don't you take a look at the tutorials provided by java?

Comment: What exactly is confusing you about Comparator? Here is the full java doc of the interface - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html

Answer (score 0):

It depends how do you want to compare it, on of solution could be:

```
@Override
public int compare(MatOfPoints mop1, MatOfPoints mop2) {
   long sumMop = 0;
   long sumMop2 = 0;
   for( Point p: mop1.toList() ){
      sumMop1 += p.x + p.y
   }
   for( Point p: mop2.toList() ){
      sumMop2 += p.x + p.y
   }
   if( sumMop1 > sumMop2)
        return 1;
    else if( sumMop1 < sumMop2 )
        return -1;
    else
        return 0;
}
```